# Exception in xul.dll and images are not shown in gecko browser inside delphi app

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, xulrunner, gecko

Using xulrunner (gecko sdk) v1.9.1.4127 browser inside Delphi 2009 app
It runs succesfully and opens requested page, but... there is no images! Moreother, in log i can see, that server sent to browser all images used in html!

Here the log:

```
[08.10.2011 19:00:09]: Got command: index.html
[08.10.2011 19:00:09]: running game....
[08.10.2011 19:00:09]: s! Content-type: text/html, size: 31990
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: browser: Waiting for 127.0.0.1…
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: browser: 
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Access violation at address 014DF56D in module 'xul.dll'. Read of address 00000014
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: browser: Transferring data from 127.0.0.1…
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: browser: Waiting for 127.0.0.1…
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Got command: game.css
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Content-type: text/css
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: s! Content-type: text/css, size: 5124
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: browser: Transferring data from 127.0.0.1…
...
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Got command: data/images/loading.gif
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Content-type: image/gif
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: s! Content-type: image/gif, size: 9370
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: browser: Transferring data from 127.0.0.1…
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: browser: Connecting to 127.0.0.1…
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: browser: Waiting for 127.0.0.1…
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Got command: jsiq.css
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Content-type: text/css
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: s! Content-type: text/css, size: 422
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Got command: data/images/title.png
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Content-type: image/png
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: s! Content-type: image/png, size: 27783
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Got command: data/images/defense/ac.jpg
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: Content-type: image/jpg
[08.10.2011 19:00:10]: s! Content-type: image/jpg, size: 1912
```

I've tried another versions of xulrunner (1.9.2.4259, 1.9.2.4280) but they falls with error inside js3250.dll :(
How to solve the problem? Or, how to know - what's the reason to error in xul.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved easily of course :)
HTTPServer served all files data via strings, then changed to serve via stream - all became normal